# Accessing apache Webserver Over local Network

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, centos6

I have installed Apache Web Server on an CentOS 6 machine and configured it to run listen on an IP X.X.X.X:8080 in httpd.conf file but it is not working when i tried to access the Web server from browser using http://x.x.x.x:8080

Comment: can you tell me what is the output of: iptables -L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default CentOS has most input ports closed in the firewall so you will almost certainly need to open port 8080 in your firewall

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

If this works then you need to save the state of the firewall

```
service iptables save
```